# ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "floor" referenced by "_psycopg.so"

Tags: python-2.7, apk, kivy, psycopg2, importerror

LogCat

[ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "floor" referenced by "_psycopg.so"(.PNG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0IIx.png)

Requirements: kivy, psycopg2

I still dont know what I am doing wrong, pls help I really want to fix this.
I did an apk with buildozer, I have been solving a lot of problems, but I don't get this. I can't find it with google, and the only thing that I have found is not even relacionated with apk or psycopg2. I really need help.

Comment: Maybe badly compiled file, or you have code that expects older/newer version of that package(check recipe for it in [p4a repo](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android)).

Comment: i solved this changing the psycopg2 with sqlite3, thanks for the help :) , now my app is working, not with heroku but is working :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, changing the psycopg2 with sqlite. Using a dinamic db, next to the main.py.

**buildozer.py**

---

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,db,ttf
requirements = kivy,sqlite3
```

**db.py**

---

```
import os

self.patch = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db = self.patch + '/databases/android.db'
```